# Twilio Android SDK vs REST API for Chat and Video

Tags: android, twilio

I used the Twilio Nodejs and Android SDK quick starter programmable chat and these work great.  I am confused by the following statement in the documentation:

*The Programmable Chat REST API allows you to control your Chat applications from the server in much the same way you can from the client, except from a service perspective rather than a 1st person one.*

Not really sure what this means?  Can I develop Android app with out the SDK and use REST API?  Why would I do that?  SDK seems to be much more flexible and easy to use.  Why would you control your app from the server?

What does "*except from a service perspective rather than 1st person one*" mean?

Comment: You can always use a REST API if one exists.  However it tends to be clunkier to use than a good SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are building an Android application then I recommend using the [Twilio Chat Android SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/sdk-download-install#android-sdk).

When the documentation references using the REST API from a service perspective it means that you can use the REST API from the perspective of your application rather than a user of the application. For example, if you need to send a message to your users that appears to come from your application admin you can do so using the REST API. That way you don't need to sign up a user and send messages from it. Alternatively, using the REST API is a good way to send and receive messages as a bot in the your chat system. You can also use the REST API to do system side maintenance on your chat instance (for example, you could close old, unused rooms using the REST API).

I hope this helps or gives you some sort of idea what you can do with the REST API. I still recommend the SDK for your user facing application though.

Comment: Hi evangelist, I have developed a chat using Twilio chat sdk, But the problem i am facing is to show user status, weather online or offline. If a user is online i am able to get his status, but when user goes offline there is no trigger i found. Please reply...

Comment: @SureshSharma you need to subscribe to your user objects to listen for update events. The event will tell you if the user has switched from online to offline or offline to online.

Comment: @evangelist, Can you please put some more light on my question or can you provide me some reference to some document or sample code for this particular feature. I am struggling with it from a long time.

Comment: Right here should help you out: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/reachability-indicator